# Get distinct values from array based on conditions within the array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59df91dae4b03289d79efb4e"),
  "name" : "TEST",
  "payload" : [ 
    {
      "_id" : "ABC",
      "status": "FALSE"
    },
    {
      "_id":"DEF",
     "status": "TRUE"
    },
    {
      "_id" : "XYZ",
     "status": "NULL"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to find all the payload._id which have status as TRUE/FALSE. 
Expected result is

```
["ABC","DEF"]
```

So far, I have something like this.

```
db.collection.distinct('payload._id',{"_id" : "TEST"})
```

Not sure how to add conditions for elements within array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query conditions with [`.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) apply to "document selection" and not the array entries contained "within" the document. If you need to "filter" array content then you apply [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) instead, as well as a little post processing to get only the "values" in the array response.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": "TEST" } },
  { "$unwind": "$payload" },
  { "$match": { "payload.status": { "$in": ["TRUE","FALSE"] } } },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$payload._id" } },
]).map( d => d._id );
```

The main parts there are the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) pipeline stage which you do primarily because you want the values from within the array to use later as the key to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on. This essentially produces a new document for each array member, but each document only contains that array member. It's "denormalizing" for MongoDB structures that contain arrays.

The next thing is the following [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline, which works like any query and only selects documents that match the conditions. Since all array members are now "documents" then non matching entries ( as documents ) get excluded. You could alternately use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to extract whilst still an array, but since we need [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) for the next stage we may as well simply `$match`.

At this point you are only left with the array entries that match the conditions. The [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is to obtain "distinct" values, so typically you would do this over a wider selection than just a single document or anything where the values here are not already distinct. So this is really just keeping all the same behavior of [`.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) intact.

Finally, since the output of [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) differs from the design of [`.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) in that it returns "documents" in results, we simply use the [`.map()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/) method to process the cursor results and return only the "values" from the specific document property as an "array".

Comment: This worked. thanks for the explanation. 
Modified the map() method as follows to run it on RoboMongo
map(function(u) { return u._id; })

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to find all the payload._id which have status as TRUE/FALSE

The query that you want to run is:

```
db.collection.distinct('payload._id', { 
  'payload.status': { $in: ["TRUE", "FALSE"] } 
})
```

A more verbose way to do it would be:

```
db.collection.distinct('payload._id', { 
  $or: [
    {'payload.status': "TRUE" },
    {'payload.status': "FALSE" }
  ]  
})
```

Comment: Query conditions in `.distinct()` do not "filter" array content. [See the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46718902/2313887).